# NOAA vdatum GDAL Variable Paths for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, datum, vertical-transformation, vertical

I want to do vertical datum conversions on geotiffs using [NOAA vdatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/welcome.html)
The conversion status menu shows no progress and no conversion happens.
I see that [Microsoft Windows needs GDAL environmental variables set](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html).
The Windows paths are...

```
C:\Program Files\GDAL 

C:\Program Files\GDAL\bin 

C:\Program Files\GDAL\bin\gdal\apps

C:\Program Files\GDAL\bin\gdal-data 

C:\Program Files\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins
```

I am running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with GDAL installed.  Do I need to set the environmental variables for Linux?  If so, I understand how to set paths (sudo -H gedit /etc/environment).

What would the paths be for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install proj-bin and proj-data from Ubuntugis unstable first.

The large vdatum files can be downloaded from http://download.osgeo.org/proj/vdatum/

Put the files in `/usr/share/proj/`. In your file system, navigate to that folder, and open a terminal to execute

```
sudo chmod 644 egm96_15.gtx
```

or whatever grid file you want to use.

Then you can run commands like

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +k=1.000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=BETA2007.gsb +geoidgrids=egm96_15.gtx +wktext -f "%.2f" <wgs84.txt >>out.txt
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96_15.gtx" <wgs84.txt >>out.txt
```

with an input file `wgs84.txt` like

```
7 51 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get vDatum to run natively in Linux because of this problem; GDAL can't be found even when the Java-specific libraries are installed in the Java PATH.

But it does run in wine! All you have to do is download the GDAL package from NOAA (https://vdatum.noaa.gov/download/sample_data/GDAL.zip) and set the environment variables (https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html#step33). One of these environment variables is PATH, which I think you have to set by editing the registry. The key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATH

Then you can run `wine 'lib\java_home\openjdk-11.0.2\bin\java' -jar vdatum.jar`